# How to publish html reports inside folder path using HTML publisher plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

To publish HTML reports using HTML publisher, I've code like

```
publishHTML([allowMissing: false, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false, includes: '*', keepAll: false, 
                    reportDir: WORKSPACE +'''/trunk/Source/target/sonar''', reportFiles: '*', 
                    reportName: 'SonarHTMLReport' + env.BUILD_NUMBER, reportTitles: ''])
```

As `reportName` has value `'SonarHTMLReport' + env.BUILD_NUMBER` it crates folder of mentioned reportName and stores reports inside it like

```
C:\Jenkins\jobs\TestPipeline\htmlreports\SonarHTMLReport343
```

But apart from this I've another reports to publish hence different folders are created like `SeleniumReport343` also other builds's report are stored at same level like say for build id `344` -

```
SonarHTMLReport344
SeleniumReport344
```

Actually I want to publish all report of specific build in its own folder say folder with build id - `343` and inside of it all it reports containing folders are stored i.e. `SonarHTMLReport343`, `SeleniumReport343` etc

But for `reportName`, if I provide value with path like `env.BUILD_NUMBER + '\SonarHTMLReport' + env.BUILD_NUMBER`, it creates folder with name `343_5cSonarHTMLReport343` instead of path `343\SonarHTMLReport343`

Is there any way using HTML publisher report I can report files under specific path?

Answer (score 0):

The issue of your report name turning `343\SonarHTMLReport343` into `343_5cSonarHTMLReport343` is because the name of the report gets HTML escaped and turned into a filename (`\` is encoded to `%5c`, and since `%` has special meaning on some OSes, that gets transformed into `_`).

If you want to publish one big html report that contains all your reports, then you must first copy every report into one single folder, e.g. `'buildreports/'+ env.BUILD_NUMBER` and then publish that folder.

However, you can also call the `publishHtml` step multiple times. You'll end up with one item in the left menu of Jenkins for each report.